# How to get a specific XML value from an XML using C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the below XML as:

```
<Requests xmlResponse="true">
<Request response="yes" responsewait="120000" sequence="1" type="Fulfillment">
<RequestData>
  <PrintControl>FTP</PrintControl>
  <User>81DF</User>
  <Documents>
    <AddressChangeLetter>
      <DocumentInfo>
        <AddressChange AddressChangeId="109346" Branch="418" LastChangeDate="">
          <Name>AAA NOVAK</Name>
          <TaxID>123123121</TaxID>
          <OldAddress1>BOX 216</OldAddress1>
          <OldAddress2>NYANE 68017</OldAddress2>
          <OldAddress3 />
          <OldAddress4 />
          <NewAddress1>P O BOX 216</NewAddress1>
          <NewAddress2>CERESCO NE 68017</NewAddress2>
          <NewAddress3 />
          <NewAddress4 />
          <DateChanged>05/08/2013</DateChanged>
          <AccountInfo AcctNum="231232311" AcctStatusCodes="IX" />
        </AddressChange>
      </DocumentInfo>
    </AddressChangeLetter>
  </Documents>
</RequestData>
```

I wanted to get the name or the value which is under the tag "Documents". Since in the above XML, the tag under the "Document" tag is "AddressChangeLetter", therefore, I want to get this name. How will I do it.

Comment: `How will I do it.` By using an XML parser like [LinqToXml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387061.aspx)

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: please do not ask people to do your homework..

Answer (score 0):

Something along the lines of... (it's not perfect, but it'll get you started - Google the functions I've used to get it working properly):

```
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.Load(yourPathGoesHere)

XmlNodeList addressNodes = xml.GetElementsByTagName("AddressChange");

foreach (XmlNode oneNode in addressNodes) {
  myVariableToGrabNames = oneNode["Name"].InnerText;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done pretty easily using [Linq to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx) e.g.

```
var xml = ...;
var xdoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
foreach (var e in xdoc.Descendants("Documents").Elements())
{
    var name = e.Name; // AddressChangeLetter
}
```